# how to check the whitespace in string and convert it into array - Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var convertToArray = (txt) => {
  let arr = txt.split(" ");
  console.log(arr);
};

convertToArray("Hello World   ");
```

At the end of `Hello World`     I have 4 spaces and now I need to take that whitespace as element of an array.

E.g.: `["Hello", "World", "    "]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`String.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) instead of `split` and filter out the single spaces. Something like:

```js
const convertToArray = (txt) => {
  return txt.match(/\s{1,}|\b(.+?)\b/g)?.filter(v => v !== ` `);
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(convertToArray("Hello World   ")));
console.log(JSON.stringify(convertToArray("   Hello World   and bye again   ")));
```

**Note**: the above will only work for words within *word boundaries* (letters (A–Z, a–z), numbers (0–9), and underscore (_)). When all characters in words should be included (like in "Hello World!   "), feel free to use this [parsing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing):

```js
console.log(
  JSON.stringify(parseWords(`Hello World!    `)));
console.log(
  JSON.stringify(parseWords(`Hello World! And    well... bye again!   `)));
// including single spaces
console.log(
  JSON.stringify(parseWords(`Hello World! And    well... bye again!   `, 1)));

function parseWords(txt, includeSingleSpaces = false) {
  let result = [txt[0]];
  txt = txt.slice(1).split('');
  
  while (txt.length) {
    const last = result[result.length - 1].at(-1);
    
    if (txt[0] === ` ` && last === ` ` || txt[0] !== ` ` && last !== ` `) {
      result[result.length - 1] += txt.shift();
      continue;
    }

    if (last !== ` ` && txt[0] === ` ` || last === ` ` && txt[0] !== ` `) {
      result.push(txt.shift());
      continue;
    }

    result[result.length - 1] += txt.shift();
    result.push(txt.shift());
  }
  
  return includeSingleSpaces ? result : result.filter(v => v !== ` `);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this code:

```
var convertToArray = (txt) => {
  let arr = txt.split(/\s+/); // Use regular expression to split by one or more spaces
  console.log(arr);
};
```